# Why is second date not giving me a value?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, date, validation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validatedates(form) {

  var x = new Date(form.post_at.value);
  var y = new Date(form.post_at_to_date.value);
  
  if (isNaN(+x) > isNaN(+y)) {
     Swal.fire({
       title: 'Dates dodgy'
     });

     return false;
  }
  
  if (x < y) {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title:  'x= ' + x + ' y= '+ y ,
        text: 'Dates seem fine!',
       // footer: '<a href="">Why do I have this issue?</a>'
      });
      //alert('From Date is before Todate');

  } else {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title:  'From Date := ' + x + ' y= '+ y ,
        text: 'Dates seem fine!',
        // footer: '<a href="">Why do I have this issue?</a>'
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

When the form is posted I get a value in the function for X  but y says invalid date!

```
<form onsubmit="validatedates(this);return false;" name="frmSearch" method="post" action="" >
  <p class="search_input">
    <label>From</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="From Date" type="date"   id="post_at" name="search[post_at]" value="<?php if (!empty($post_at))echo $post_at; ?>" class="input-control"/>
    <label>To</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="To Date" type="date" id="post_at_to_date" name="search[post_at_to_date]" style="margin-left:10px" value="<?php if (!empty($post_at_to_date)) echo $post_at_to_date; ?>" class="input-control"/>          
     <p class="mb-4" align="right"><button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-success" value="Search"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Run Selection</button></p>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Is `$post_at_to_date` set? What happens if you put `<?php echo $post_at_to_date; ?>` above the start of the form? Do you get what you expect?

Comment: `says invalid date`...where/how? That error message isn't mentioned in your JS code.

Comment: general debugging tip: console.log all variables until you figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Aside: what is the point of the `if (x < y) {...` clause? In either case you are outputting the exact same message.

Comment: `if (isNaN(+x) > isNaN(+y)) {`...doesn't really make a lot of sense. isNAN will return true or false, so asking whether true > false (for example), although technically possible, doesn't seem very logical. What do you think this clause is supposed to do? It's a bit difficult to work out what you're actually trying to validate with this.

Comment: The use of [unary `+`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-unary-plus-operator) in `isNaN(+x)` is redundant since the value passed to [*isNaN*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-isnan-number) is first converted to number by [*ToNumber*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type), which is exactly what unary `+` does.

Comment: Thank you. I wil get back with my findings a.s.a.P. I am not a programmer just a dabbler. I am writing a reporting tool using php, Javascript and datatables.

Comment: OK that's fine, but you do at least need to be able to clarify what you're trying to achieve with the code you've posted

Comment: There is a startdate Date Picker and and enddate Date picker. When these are selected they pass the values to an ajax call that filters a datatables by the values selected. This part is working fine. However, I am trying to validate the dates that are picked i.e. if the enddate is less than the start date then warn user!

Comment: I think it's something to do with the date formats between php & Javascri[pt. when the date is selected is is e.g. 1st February 2022 When in the Javascript it returns Jan 02 2022

Comment: Javascript will assume the date string is in m/d/Y format unless you do something else to inform it otherwise. If you need to parse a non-US date format I'd suggest probably using one of the many JS date libraries available. (Although the standard HTML5 date picker outputs the date in Y-m-d format anyway though, so it shouldn't normally be an issue. Are you using some custom date picker?)

Comment: I see that you've tried to use `type="date"` to get a standard datepicker in your form, but unfortunately you forgot to remove the `type="text"` from the same elements so it didn't work. Remove those and you can use the standard HTML5 datepicker control. And once you do that, the date comparison code becomes trivial - Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8aw14puj/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. I am still learning to code. Mainly because i enjoy it. I doubt very much if I will ever be a developer but I like what I'm doing. I will check your fiddle and get back to you.